# VBA Concatenation not working

Tags: vba, excel

Hello guys my VBA concatenation is not working.
So over here I am importing the complete page, but I need only the price to be imported as I was unable to do that now I am fetching data from the page to a sheet and then transferring to different sheet .

So if u guys have any idea how to do it, please help me solving this issues.

```
Dim value As String
value = 161631397677#
For x = 1 To 2
    Debug.Print value
    With Sheet1.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;http://www.ebay.in/itm/" & "value", _
        Destination:=Sheet1.Range("$A$9"))
```

This is how I used concatenation but it is not working.
It is not fetching the result from browser.
I tried doing this using multiple value but was unable to fetch data from the browser. I want to generate something like this:

> http://www.ebay.in/itm/161631397677

from

```
With Sheet1.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;http://www.ebay.in/itm/" & "value", _
        Destination:=Sheet1.Range("$A$9"))
```

So please help me guys resolving this issue .I am new to VBA don't have much knowledge about it.

Comment: Try `"URL;http://www.ebay.in/itm/" & value,...`

Comment: I tried @Jeeped bro but it is not working.

Comment: I tried @Jeeped bro it worked for single variable,When passing multiple it is not working .

Comment: We don't know what `x` has to do with the code you posted. Go back and edit the question to include enough code that we can see what is going on in the loop. What you've shown simply does the exact same thing twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) don't use "value" as name of the variable. It's a reserved word. Use something else (like "MyValue")

2) it's better (or "more proper") to create your variable outside the QueryTables

3) You use the variable **value** as string "value" in the concatenation.

**It should look like this**:

```
Dim MyValue As String
MyValue = 161631397677#
MyURL = "URL;http://www.ebay.in/itm/" & MyValue
For x = 1 To 2
    Debug.Print MyValue
    With Sheet1.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        MyURL, _
        Destination:=Sheet1.Range("$A$9"))
```

EDIT: The place of the line: `MyURL = "URL;http://www.ebay.in/itm/" & MyValue` depends on the use of your loop **For x = 1 To 2**
it will be inside or outside that loop.

Comment: for single value its working fine but when i pass it in an array Dim Myarray(0 To 1) As String
Myarray(0) = 161631397677#
Myarray(1) = 141599734375#

 
 For x = 1 To 2
 With Sheet1.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;http://www.ebay.in/itm/" & Myarray(0) To (1), _
    Destination:=Sheet1.Range("$A$9"))

Its not working.Please help me

Comment: It's 2 different connection strings or one string with the two numbers in it? Depending on that, I will be able to give you the answer...

Comment: It's two different strings.I am passing in an array so that i can fetch both the values at the same time @DataSmarter

Comment: but then, you have (as someone mentioned in another answer) two times the same destination -> the cell A9 on the Sheet1... So this approach will not work. Why you don't just make a loop to add one table in Sheet1 and the other on the Sheet2 (= example).  In top of that, I am not sure that the syntax using an array in the  QueryTable is correct. I don't really see the added value of using an array for that...

Comment: or anyone . can you help me what should be the exact syntax over here With Sheet1.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _ "URL;ebay.in/itm/"; & Myarray(0 to 1).Thanks

Comment: or anyone . can you help me what should be the exact syntax over here With Sheet1.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _ "URL;ebay.in/itm/"; & Myarray(0 to 1).Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The range is static, you want to stack Pivot tables on top of one another. They [may not overlap](http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-components-postattachments/00-00-73-84-73/overlap.JPG).